# LINUX BASH SET ECHO

Tags: linux, bash, echo

```
set character = ( a b c d e f g )
echo $character[1]
echo $character[2-5]
```

I don't know why I got wrong bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('. Can someone help me please

Comment: First you have to put them between braces {}, and second use `:` instead of `-`. And do not forget to keep them quoted. So, you'll have `"${character[1]}"` and `"${character[2:5]}"`.

Comment: The close reason is slightly misleading here. We used to have a "too broad" close reason which included something like "fails to exhibit basic understanding of the concepts"; but the new(-ish) "needs more focus" is more specifically about many questions in one. The more correct close reason for this would now be "needs details or clarity" (especially then clarity).

Answer (score 1):

In the bash shell, `set` is used to control the numbered variables like `$0`, `$1`, etc. and shell option settings.

For other shell variables you just set them. Like this:

```
character=(a b c d e f g)
echo "${character[1]}"
```

Although I suppose that you can use `declare` or `local` as necessary.

You need to use the bracket characters like `${variable}` because that works for all Bourne compatible shells and won't result in weird results even if the shell does not understand arrays. It'll just come out blank.

I am not sure what you expect with your third line, but `[2-5]` will not create an array slice of 2 through 5. It will evaluate to `-3` which will start at the back of the array and count back `-3` to produce `e`.